# Excel VBA, Error '438' "object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure I'm being a bit thick here but can't for the life of me see why this run-time error is occurring. Here's the code:

```
Public Sub fRTWIni()

Dim varList As Variant
Dim intR As Integer
Dim con As Control

varList = fGetList("ct_adt_RTWYesNo", "ORDER BY RTWYesNo ASC")

For Each con In UF_ReturnToWork.frmRTW.Controls
    If TypeName(con) = "ComboBox" And con.Name <> "cbRTWHH" And con.Name <> "cbRTWMM" Then
        con.ColumnCount = 2
        con.ColumnWidth = 0
        For intR = LBound(varList, 2) To UBound(varList, 2)
            con.AddItem intR
            con.Column(1, intR) = varList(1, intR)
        Next intR
    End If
Next con

End Sub
```

The error is occurring on line:

```
For Each con In UF_ReturnToWork.frmRTW.Controls
```

`UF_ReturnToWork` is a userform.
`frmRTW` is a frame.

I've used this method plenty of times to access the controls with a userform / frame and am absolutely stumped as to why I can't use is now.

As far as I'm aware and from my research, `.Controls` is a member of the object and therefore I can't understand why it wont allow me to use it.

Any ideas why the error is occurring?

Thanks
Gareth

Comment: Place `UF_ReturnToWork.frmRTW.Controls` in the watch window to see if it returns a collection of controls, as you'd expect.

Comment: @shahkalpesh it returns `<Object variable or With block variable not set>`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in:

```
con.ColumnWidth = 0
```

should be

```
con.ColumnWidths = 0
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I looked at it for far too long to spot that!